# Archivo pack en repositorio excesivamente grande

Tags: git

Recientemente cloné un respositorio que contiene unos cuantos archivos de Python y plantillas de Jinja, pero al revisar el tamaño del repositorio me di cuenta que tiene mas de 130 megas.

Revisé el directorio y encontré en `.git\objects\pack` un archivo que tiene estos 130 megas.

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-ar--     11/05/2017  11:32 a. m.     201356 pack-9da98c5cce72bd8da0a68ec2594dedec9ae48d24.idx
-ar--     11/05/2017  11:32 a. m.  133944653 pack-9da98c5cce72bd8da0a68ec2594dedec9ae48d24.pack
```

### Preguntas

1. ¿Qué son esos archivos `.pack`?
2. ¿Puedo borrarlos sin preocupaciones o contienen información importante relacionada con mi repositorio?
3. Si no puedo borrarlos directamente, ¿cómo puedo reducir su tamaño?

> Solo se me ocurre que tenga un histórico de archivos... Es el repositorio de mi blog personal y en algún momento guardé ahí archivos de gran tamaño, aunque ahora solo tiene archivos de texto y este `.pack`...

Cloné el repositorio en Windows 8, pero suelo ocupar macOS Sierra o alguna variedad de Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Qué son esos archivos .pack?

Esos son los archivos que Git crea cuando intenta ahorrar espacio. Básicamente, Git toma varios objetos e intenta combinarlos en un solo archivo binario, el pack file, aplicándole compresión para ahorrar espacio.

Referencia: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles.

> ¿Puedo borrarlos sin preocupaciones o contienen información importante relacionada con mi repositorio?

No, no puedes borrarlos sin corromper tu repositorio.

> Si no puedo borrarlos directamente, ¿cómo puedo reducir su tamaño?

La verdad es que no puedes. Git ya está tratando de reducir el tamaño del repositorio usando los pack files.

Tal como sospechastes, Git mantiene el historial completo de tu repositorio. De modo que, aunque ahora solo tengas archivos texto pequeños, si en algún momento en la historia del repositorio tuvistes archivos grandes, sobre todo archivos binarios que tal vez no beneficien tanto de compresión, entonces esto explicaría porqué el repositorio está más grande de lo que esperas.

Si deseas reducir el tamaño de tu repositorio, tendrías que producir un repositorio distinto que no incluya todo el historial, en particular la parte del historial que incluye los archivos grandes.

Comment: Buena idea, estaba pensando en mover el repositorio a gitlab y me detuvo el tamaño de ese archivo. Gracias. Por cierto, que si se puede: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big

Comment: @toledano: si vas a borrarlos, en vez de seguir esos consejos de 2009 o 2011, échale un vistazo a la página de manual de `git filter-branch`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch